# What does the blank, blue and red highlight signify in llvm-cov coverage data?

Tags: c, testing, llvm, code-coverage

The [Documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html#gap-regions) mentions that:

> Gap regions are used to eliminate unnatural artifacts in coverage
> reports, such as red “unexecuted” highlights present at the end of an
> otherwise covered line, or blue “executed” highlights present at the
> start of a line that is otherwise not executed.

Can someone please explain what the line means and what am I supposed to infer from the colors.

Also, if someone could explain what the number on hover and the side means, it would be of great help.

I tried to readup other code coverage tools but all tools have different meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's poorly documented isn't it?

This is my best guess:

- white background are executed or irrelevant lines (like comments)
- the blue number in the left column is the count of executions of that line

  - blue background regions call out a section *within* a line for its own execution count which you can see on hover (I think this is accounted for in the line count column; i.e. the sum of all the "gap"(?) counts on a line should be less than or equal to the line-wide count)
- red are unexecuted sections of code

I'm not sure I understand the paragraph about "gap regions", but I think they are just for more granularity of coverage.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The red regions with line numbers in red means that the lines entirely were not executed. But conditional statements with red and blue highlights say that the lines have been conditionally executed or not executed. On hover, it also shows the number of times this has happened. Thanks, I forgot I had asked this question. It took me a lot of time to understand what the documentation wants to say.